i want to disable floating window android in all smart phone
In my Flutter code, I want to stop floating windows. I added specific settings to the Android manifest, and it works on stock Android but not on OnePlus UI or One UI (or similar custom UIs).
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:resizeableActivity="false"
  android:supportsPictureInPicture="false"
  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
  android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
  android:exported="true"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

How can I block floating windows universally on all smartphones?


my code

It better to add your code as part of the question, rather than as a comment. You can edit your question to add in the code.
